# Dropdown en dropdown Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

estuve intentando pero no lo pude lograr correctamente... Y se que puede ser algo muy tonto, pero apenas estoy familiarizándome del todo con este Framework.

Lo que quiero hacer es un dropdown, dentro de un dropdown osea

```
item 1 -> titulo
item 2|      mas items 1
item 3|      mas items 2
```

Algo asi... en html regular y eso si lo he hecho, pero con Bootstrap nunca, alguno puede darme una idea? probé esto

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4">
  <div class="btn-group dropright">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropright
  </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="right-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(111px, 0px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">item 1</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">item 2</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Item 3</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Pero no, no funciona como debería.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Lo quieres hacer es un menu desplebable dentro de un item del menu?

Comment: Exacto - que al poner el mouse sobre el item 1 se vea uno a un lado con un titulo, y debajo del titulo mas items